# Validation before confirmation popup in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am using 2 jquery plugins, 1 for validation (jquery.validate.js) and 1 for my confirmation window using modal popup (jquery.blockUI.js). Both of these plugins work fine in my php form. However, I'd like to have the validation trigger before displaying the modal popup which isn't what's happening. I've placed both inside a single function triggered by a button like so:

```
<input type="button" value = "Submit" onclick="javascript:showActions();" />

function showActions() {
    $("#registration-form").valid();

    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#confirmation-dialog'),
        css: {
            width: '500px',
            display: 'block'
        }
    });
}
```

What happens when I try to trigger the function is, it validates the form but at the same time displays the modal popup which disables the form until it is closed. How can I make it so that I would only call the modal popup if all validations are met?

I've tried adding an if condition which checks if $("#registration-form").valid() returns true or false but when I do this, I end up with a blank popup window and my validation does not work. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
function showActions() {
    if ($("#registration-form").valid()) {
        $.blockUI({
            message: $('#confirmation-dialog'),
            css: {
                width: '500px',
                display: 'block'
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I thought I needed to add == true or false on the condition statement when this was all I had to do. Thanks a lot man.